# Transaction ID through Websocket

Tags: transaction, websocket

Is it possible to receive the latest transaction id from a wallet using websocket?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can (though only indirectly)! You can listen to account changes using a websocket and then fetch the latest transaction involving your wallet once an account change is picked up:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
const pubkey = new PublicKey('<Your public key here>');
connection.onAccountChange(
    pubkey,
    async () => {
        const latestSig = await connection.getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2(pubkey);
        console.log('Latest tx signature is', latestSig[0]);
    },
    'confirmed',
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have a similar setup where I use accountSubscribe from the webhook as the trigger, but instead of getting the most recent transaction id, I am receiving the second most recent id. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In some cases your websocket might be a bit faster than your RPC connection when indexing the latest on-chain state which might cause this. I'd suggest adding some code to track the initial most recent transaction. Then when you fetch a new transaction after getting notice from the websocket, you can check if it's the same as your most recent one, and, if it is, retry fetching after a few miliseconds.